# Ordre des mots dans une combinaison de termes négatifs

Tags: négation, ordre-des-mots

Est-ce qu'on peut dire

> Personne n'a jamais plus rien dit à ce sujet ?

Ou faut-il bien dire

> Personne n'a plus jamais rien dit à ce sujet ?

Pourquoi ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux formulations sont correctes et de même registre (courant); mais la seconde est préférée. Personnellement, je dirais que la seconde est préférable parce qu'on n'a pas une impression que « plus » modifierait « rien », mais c'est une impression assez subjective.

[image]

[a jamais plus rien](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20jamais%20plus%20rien%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

[a plus jamais rien](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20plus%20jamais%20rien%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Comment: J'ajoute que Grevisse mentionne "jamais plus" et "plus jamais" en passant comme exemples interchangeable dans la section qui traite des auxiliaire de négation multiples ("On peut dire: Il ne reviendra plus jamais, ou jamais plus.").

Answer (score 0):

« n’a jamais plus rien dit » me paraît légèrement plus soutenu, « n’a plus jamais rien dit » me paraît légèrement plus familier (les deux étant tout à fait valides et du registre courant comme l'a dit LPH).

Pour étayer un peu cette impression qui est aussi assez subjective : « Jamais plus » me fait penser à la traduction de Baudelaire du poème *Le Corbeau* d’Edgar Allan Poe, tandis que « Plus jamais » m’évoque des slogans qu'on pourrait voir en politique, ou lors de manifestations.